# How to build binary packages in Launchpad?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, build

I have a Launchpad account and a PPA. I have just uploaded a source package using `dput`.

Is it possible to instruct the Launchpad build machine to build binary packages?

Answer (score 5):

The following quote from the [help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) for packaging and using PPA makes it clear that the build machines at Launchpad.net automatically builds binary packages.

> Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build
>   binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.

So, if you have properly packaged your source and the source is built without errors, then the Launchpad.net would have built binary packages for you and then send you an email when it completes. You can check the status of your packages on the following page:

https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+archive/ppa